# Storing Service Account Username and Password

Tags: java, security, service-accounts

I am building a java web application that will automatically grant users Administrative Rights to their Windows PC's when a manager approves their request.

In order to accomplish this, I am going to write a script to automatically remote into the users computer and add them to the computer's administrative group. I figured in order to do this though, I will need to have an Administrative Service Account to access all computers.

My question would be, how can I go about securely storing the Administrative Service Account information? The application will need the credentials every time it needs to go and give a user admin-rights, so how can I go about letting the application use the Service Account without human interaction? Obviously I cant just put admin credentials in a plain-text properties file. The credentials shouldn't be open for any developers to see who might go in and change the application later.

Could there be a better way to do this? Someone mentioned to me once maybe having an account in Active Directory to impersonate, but I wasn't able to follow up for more details on that.

Comment: Just to be clear, the program that remotes in is supposed to have the credentials, not the client account that requests admin, right?

Comment: Correct. A user will log into the web application to request admin rights. They will input their username, computer name and other company info. Once the request is approved, the program will use the service account that has admin credentials to remote in and add the user to the Administrator group.

Answer (score 0):

There is one method of protecting service account passwords that is occasionally used for services that use databases is based on the concept of inversion of control.

Here the service can call a stored procedure, which has anonymous access, that prompts the database to generate, set, and send the password to the service, whose address it knows, via a separate call.

While the anon call is normally IP limited to prevent DoS attacks, it doesn't matter if some other process calls it, because the stored procedure will only send the password to the service regardless of who calls it.